# Why does my functions.php cause white-screen and media-library issues?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, uploads, child-theme

### **Overview:**

I was authoring a child-theme, and realized that functions.php was causing problems with the media-library and caused a "white-screen" to appear after editing a post. I fixed the issue by removing all content from my functions.php, but I don't know what was causing this.

---

### Info:

**Production Server:** multi-site, Wordpress 3.8.1 **Local development server**(aka "localhost"): Wordpress 3.8.1 with AMPPS v2.2(php v5.3) in Windows 7 Pro SP1.

---

### **The Media-Library problem:**

- Upon going to appearance-->Header-->'select image'-->'choose an image from your media library'
- **AND** Upon going to posts-->'all posts'-->'edit post'-->'set-featured image'
- The media library did not show any content, as if my library were empty. This is in spite of going to dashboard-->media-->library, and verifying that there is media-content.
- Also, when attempting to upload a media file (using the above ways), I would always receive an error "an error occurred in the upload. Please try again later"

---

### The White-Screen problem:

- Upon going to posts-->all posts-->edit post--> update, a white-screen would ensue when clicking the button to update/create a post.
- Using `CNTRL+s` to save the post from within the wysiwyg did not cause a white-screen.

---

### functions.php

This is what functions.php looked like before I fixed the problem by removing all the content.(It turns out that I no longer needed the functions within it anyways). Also on http://pastebin.com/KS66yfqK

```
<!-- In a child theme, all of the functions of the parent theme are present, unless   overridden here -->
<?php

function cals_fetch_feed2($feed_uri,$num_items, $echo = 1, $length =-1, $exclude=''){
//NOTE: to disable cache, go to feed.php and replace timestamp in 
// $feed->set_cache_duration(apply_filters('wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', 43200, $url)); 
$i = rand(1,5);
// Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed($feed_uri);

if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly 

    //enable order by date
    $rss->enable_order_by_date(true);

    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to $num_items. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity($num_items); 

    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif;

if($echo == 1){

    if (count($rss_items) == 0) {
        //echo '<li>No items.</li>';
        echo 'no items';
    } else {
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) { 

            //check for excluded posts
            if($exclude!='' && $exclude == $item->get_id()){
                continue;
            }


            $featuredImageSrc = $item->get_item_tags('', 'featuredimage'); 


            $featuredImage = $featuredImageSrc[0]['data'];



            ?>

            <?php  
            /*if($featuredImage) {*/

                echo '<div class="newsItem fromFunctionsPHP ';
                if(!$featuredImage) {echo 'noImage ';}




                foreach ($item->get_categories() as $category)
                    {
                        echo $category->get_label()." ";


                        /*$imageCat = $category->get_label();

                    if($imageCat == "Agriculture" || $imageCat == "Food" || $imageCat == "Environment" || $imageCat == "Energy" || $imageCat == "Health" || $imageCat == "People" || $imageCat == "Communities" || $imageCat == "Events") {

                        break;

                    } else {


                        echo "Announcements ";
                        break;
                    }*/

                    }

                echo '"><div class="previousa"><div class="additionalContent">';

                $notdisplayed = true;

            if($featuredImage1) {
                echo '<img src="'.$featuredImage1.'" alt="" />';
            } else if($featuredImage) {
                echo '<img src="'.$featuredImage.'" alt="" />';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="noImageSpacer"></div>';
                /*foreach ($item->get_categories() as $category)
                {
                    $imageCat = $category->get_label();

                    if($imageCat == "Agriculture") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/agriculture-pic-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else if($imageCat == "Food") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/food-pic-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else if($imageCat == "Environment") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/environment-pic-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else if($imageCat == "Energy") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/energy-pic-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else if($imageCat == "Health") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/health-pic-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else if ($imageCat == "People" || $imageCat == "Communities") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/people-pic-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else if ($imageCat == "Events") {

                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/twitter-bg-';
                        echo rand(1,3);
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        break;
                    } else {


                        echo '<img src="';
                        echo bloginfo('template_url');
                        echo '/images/generalcals-bg-';
                        echo $i;
                        echo '.jpg" alt=" " />';
                        if($i < 5) {
                            $i = $i + 1;
                        } else {
                            $i = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    }



                }*/


            }
            echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="text"><div class="glyph"><div class="symbol"></div></div><div class="titleheading"><h3>';
                $title = $item->get_title();
                if($length != -1){
                    if(strlen($title)>$length){ 
                        echo substr($title,0,$length).'...'; } 
                    else { 
                        echo $title; 
                    }
                } else { 
                    echo $title; 
                }
            echo '</h3></div><div class="excerpt">';
            $content = $item->get_description(); 
            echo $content;
            echo '</div><div class="dateheading">';
            echo $item->get_date('F j, Y');
            echo '</div><div class="hiddendate">';
            echo "-".$item->get_date('Ymd');
            echo '</div><div class="hiddengroup">';
            $cattemp = $item->get_category();
            echo $cattemp->get_label();
            echo '</div><span class="number">10</span></div>';





        echo '<a href="';
        echo $item->get_permalink();
        echo '" class="highlight" title="';
        echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a');
        echo '">Read more about ';
        echo $item->get_title();
        echo '<div class="loadingSpinner"><div class="progress"></div></div></a></div></div>';


        /*}  else {

            //What to display if no image is supplied by the article

            echo '<div class="newsItem noImage ';
                foreach ($item->get_categories() as $category)
                    {
                        echo $category->get_label()." ";
                    }

                echo '"><div class="previousa"><div class="titleheading"><h3>';
                $title = $item->get_title();
                if($length != -1){
                    if(strlen($title)>$length){ 
                        echo substr($title,0,$length).'...'; } 
                    else { 
                        echo $title; 
                    }
                } else { 
                    echo $title; 
                }
            echo '</h3></div><div class="text"><div class="glyph"><div class="symbol"></div></div><div class="excerpt">';
            $content = $item->get_description(); 
            echo $content;
            echo '</div><div class="dateheading">';
            echo $item->get_date('F j, Y');
            echo '</div><div class="hiddendate">';
            echo "-".$item->get_date('Ymd');
            echo '</div><div class="hiddengroup">';
            $cattemp = $item->get_category();
            echo $cattemp->get_label();
            echo '</div><span class="number">10</span></div><div class="additionalContent">';









        echo '</div><a href="';
        echo $item->get_permalink();
        echo '" class="highlight" title="';
        echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a');
        echo '">Read more about ';
        echo $item->get_title();
        echo '<div class="loadingSpinner"><div class="progress"></div></div></a></div></div>';


        }*/
         ?>




        <?php }
    }

} else {

    return $rss_items;

}
}

/*function soilsextension_enqueue_scripts(){
 $handle = 'soilsextension_scripts';
 $src = get_theme_root_uri() . '/soilsextension/js/min/master.min.js';

wp_register_script($handle, $src, false, false, true);

wp_enqueue_script('soilsextension_scripts');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'soilsextension_enqueue_scripts'); */
```

---

### Active Plugins:

These were the active plugins during the time I was testing.

**Production:** Advanced Custom Fields Version 4.3.5 (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), Custom Post type UI Version 0.8.2 (http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/custom-post-type-ui/), Events Manager Version 5.5.2(http://wp-events-plugin.com/), WP Super Cache Version 1.4 (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)

**Localhost Active plugins:** Advanced Custom Fields Version 4.3.4 (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), Custom Post type UI Version 0.8.2 (http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/custom-post-type-ui/)

---

**Attempted Solutions:**
I attempted two cases and recorded the results, in effort to understand the cause.

> > **Case 1.**
> >
> > > removing html comment on top of functions.php
> > >
> > > > **Localhost:** "white-screen problem" is absent. "media-library problem", absent.
> > > >
> > > > **Production:** "White-screen problem" and "media-library problem both present.
> >
> > **Case 2.**
> >
> > > keeping html comment on top of functions.php but removing function cals_feed_fetch2
> > >
> > > > **Localhost:** "white-screen problem" is absent." media-file problem" present.
> > > >
> > > > **Production:** "white-screen problem" is present. media-file problem is present

---

### Conclusion:

---

Though I appear to have fixed the problems by removing all the content in functions.php, I don't know what part(s) of my original functions.php caused these problems.

Comment: Does your server have errors on? How about [Debug Mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) ?

Comment: In my organization, I typically don't review the server error logs. Yes I did use Debug mode in the production server and set `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` to help testing.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is just an HTML comment outside the scope of PHP. It'll output with every response and creates all the kinds of headaches you're experiencing.

Solution? Remove it, or make it a PHP comment:

```
<?php    
/* In a child theme, all of the functions of the parent theme are present, unless   overridden here */
```

You should also make sure there's no whitespace either side of PHP tags, as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Case 1, where I removed the html comment, yielded different results between my local and production site. It worked locally, but not on the production server. I looked at my git commit logs, and I did indeed have one blank line before the functions.php file, when I was testing.

Comment: Are there any other files (other than theme files like `page.php`) that could have whitespace outside PHP tags? Check 'em all!

Answer (score 0):

for problem with display media in wordpress you must:

remove comment between php tags like below

```
<?php some functions ?>
```

comment line for guide --> this part cause your media doesn't show

```
<?php more functions ?>
```

i hope that is useful for everyone that have problem